# The JWPlayer not playing .mov, only playing audio

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7, .mov

The JWPlayer not playing .mov files, It's playing only audio.
It has no problem with .mp4 in all browsers.

Here is my code for embedding videos.

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/YOUR_JW_PLAYER_ACCOUNT_TOKEN.js" ></script>

 <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
       file: "http://localhost/test2/1.mov",
       image: "1.jpg",
       width: 740,
       height: 460
    });
</script>
```

[JWPlayer](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support) media format support says it can play .mov[image]

Here is the error:

[image]

What are the exact file formats supported by the JWPlayer? There are many formats in details like H.264 HD/SD, PROPRES HQ 23.98, DVCPRO 100, DV-25, etc.

Comment: Once again, those who don't know what JW Player is think that this question is unclear. There's nothing unclear about it - the intent, and the problem, are crystal clear. Just because YOU don't understand the question, you can't assume that there's a problem with the question.

Comment: I agree that it is perfectly clear what is being asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMV files are not supported in JW Player, since they can't be played either natively or even with a Flash plugin on most platforms. Your MOV file may fail to play if it's not encoded correctly.

Save yourself all kinds of heartache, and convert everything to MP4. Free program:

http://handbrake.fr/

Take the default settings, plus check "Web optimized." You can even batch-process entire folders full of videos.

Edit: Yes, JW Player can play a MOV file, but only if it's properly encoded as H.264. Just having the right file extension isn't enough - not all MOV's are created equal. Please give us a link to your site, so we can check the actual file you're feeding to the player. Or, just convert to MP4, and save yourself the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

We only support the following:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support